# Counting if a multi-choice cell contains a value from another cell

Tags: excel

I have the following formula

```
=COUNTIFS(NAME!H:H;C2;NAME!D:D;">="&'Weekly Status'!A2;NAME!D:D;"<="&'Weekly Status'!B2)
```

Cells in column H in the separate NAME sheet are drop downs which have VBA to allow multiple choice.  When one choice is selected, the cell containing the above counts correctly.  However, if there are two or more numbers, it doesn't count any.

Row C just has numbers 1 to 29 (Just has the H column in the other sheet has 1 to 29 as the options to chose from.

The remainder of the formula is just getting figures based on a date range we want to look up and this functions correctly.

Thanks in advance.

I need to find a way to check if any value in the H column cell contains the value being checked against in the C row.

Comment: It would help to help you if you provide some sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, I found a way that works.  Not sure if it is the cleanest but it'll do.

```
=COUNTIFS(NAME!H:H;"*"&C2&"*";NAME!D:D;">="&'Weekly Status'!A2;NAME!D:D;"<="&'Weekly Status'!B2)+COUNTIFS(NAME!H:H;C2;NAME!D:D;">="&'Weekly Status'!A2;NAME!D:D;"<="&'Weekly Status'!B2)
```

By adding `"*"&C2&"*"` it uses the wildcard to search for the number anywhere in the cell but this only worked when there was more than one number selected in the H column i.e. 2 and 3.  If 2 was selected on its own, it wouldn't count.  This is why I added the + countif to search for just the sole number.